# Material Drawer In Eclipse Isse

Tags: android, android-listview, material-design, android-logcat, android-toolbar

i want to add material drawer in android app ...so we need we have to include a toolbar ..
but when we include toolbar i got error
my Code for activitymain_xml  is

```
       <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_parent_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
           </FrameLayout>

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
      <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#004869"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:textColor="#f9f5f5"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            />

          </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

         </LinearLayout>
```

code for toolbar is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background"/>
```

code for include toolbar is

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

My Style.xml is

```
    <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> 
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    </style>

   </resources>
```

My Mainifiest file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lifegoal.eshop"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity
            android:name="com.lifegoal.eshop.Splash_Screen_Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </manifest>
```

But I got error like

```
   04-28 12:53:05.632: E/AndroidRuntime(3181): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lifegoal.eshop/com.lifegoal.eshop.Home_Screen_Activity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
   04-28 12:53:05.632: E/AndroidRuntime(3181):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
   04-28 12:53:05.632: E/AndroidRuntime(3181):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
```

Guys I Need ur help ..thx in advance

Comment: Can you show your `styles.xml` ?

Comment: Please post your AndroidManifest.xml and styles.xml

Comment: run after removing `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` this line.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't override the styles.xml  in values-vxx folder? for example v21.

Comment: Make the style with no action bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your `style.xml` like below It works for me:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    </style>

</resources>
```

According to developers guide we have to use `NoActionBar` theme to use toolbar as a action bar. 
Also `extends` your activity with `ActionBarActivity`.

**Edit**
Use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`, It is deprecated.

Comment: You should extend AppCompatActivity. ActionBarActivity now is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do following :-
Remove this line from your `toolbar.xml`:-

```
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
```

And add this line in your activitymain_xml file:-

```
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
```

And extend parent theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: it dosent help me @Rajat

Comment: Are you getting same error or different error after changing this ?

Answer (score 0):

> AppCompat does not support the current theme features

Seems like, your style of Theme is wrong.

Your `style.xml` should contain these lines:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

**P.S.** : Your Theme should extend `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` instead of `Theme.AppCompat.Light`

Comment: try with  `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` instead of `Theme.AppCompat.Light`